# Global variable troubles

Tags: c++, function, variables, arduino, global

I would like some variables `*pin_ledID` declared and initialized in one function `rgbInitiate()` to be recognized by any other function ; For example `rgbMixer()`.  As you can see, I've tried returning the values and declaring them as external variables, but nothing has worked. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks. =)

```
int rgbInitiate(int ledID, int redpin, int greenpin, int bluepin) {
    extern int redpin_ledID;
    extern int greenpin_ledID;
    extern int bluepin_ledID;
    redpin_ledID = redpin;
    greenpin_ledID = greenpin;
    bluepin_ledID = bluepin;
    pinMode(redpin_ledID, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenpin_ledID, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bluepin_ledID, OUTPUT);
    return redpin_ledID;
    return greenpin_ledID;
    return bluepin_ledID;
}

void rgbMixer(int ledID, int redvalue, int greenvalue, int bluevalue) {
    analogWrite(redpin_ledID, redvalue);
    analogWrite(greenpin_ledID, greenvalue);
    analogWrite(bluepin_ledID, bluevalue);
}
```

Comment: A function can only return a single value of the type preceding the function name. A "return" statement defines this value *and immediately terminates the execution of the function*. "extern" has no relation whatsoever to the return of a value in a function. - You can't start programming without learning the fundamentals such as these.

Answer (score 0):

well…

when I first read your answer, I thought wtf does he want global variables? 
But then I read your code (and reformatted it so it was clear that this code is non-sense)… And then I though *OMFG!*

I can't emphasize more the comment of @laune:

> You can't start programming without learning the fundamentals such as these.

So what you wrote makes no sense for C or C++. My first advice to you would be to read [that book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) (you can find it as ebook easily) and maybe a good book on C++ in your language.

- global variables are bad and should be avoided as much as possible

Usually only exceptions to that rule is often [*singletons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that are often used in Arduino codes mostly because of the design choice to have split the `main()` function entry point in two functions `setup()` and `loop()`.

- the way you use the `extern` keyword is just plain non-sense

I don't know where to begin with that situation, except maybe giving you links to documentation to read on the topic:

- [The K&R Book](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf) page 31
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable
- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/

  - when you do a `return` the function execution thread ends…

So there's no point in having multiple returns in one execution thread, all the following will never be executed and is considered as dead code.

But apart from this teaching lesson, what you want to do is quite simple, and you can achieve this by using preprocessor macros (which is the usual way for your use case):

```
#define LED_RED_PIN 12
#define LED_GREEN_PIN 11
#define LED_BLUE_PIN 10

void setup_leds() {
    pinMode(LED_RED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED_GREEN_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED_BLUE_PIN, OUTPUT)
}

void rgb_mixer(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
    analogWrite(LED_RED_PIN, redvalue);
    analogWrite(LED_GREEN_PIN, greenvalue);
    analogWrite(LED_BLUE_PIN, bluevalue);
}

void setup() {
    setup_leds();
}

void loop() {
    rgb_mixer(128, 128, 128);
}
```

You may want to be smart about defining the three led at once, and there are ways to do it. You can create a class that contains the data about the three LEDs, you can write a macro that sets up the three LEDs in one elegant line…

But I'm won't give you any hint like that, because before trying to be smart, you need to **learn**, **experiment** and **fail**. Once you've been through that process, you'll have learned the basics of programming and the C language, and what's the object oriented programing, and what's C++ etc… 
You'll have earned the right to be smart, and you'll figure out those neat ways by yourself!

Until then, have a good read and good luck!

Ok, from what you write I think what you want is the following:

```
class RGBMixer {
    uint8_t _red, _green, _blue;
    public:
        RGBMixer();
        void begin(uint8_t r_pin, uint8_t g_pin, uint8_t b_pin) {
            _red = r;
            _green = g;
            _blue = b;
            pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
        }        
        void mix(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
            analogWrite(_red, r);
            analogWrite(_green, g);
            analogWrite(_blue, b);
        }      
} rgb_mixer;

void setup() {
    rgb_mixer.begin(10, 11, 12);
}

void loop() {
    rgb_mixer.mix(128, 128, 128);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should explain more.  The code I provided is part of an arduino library.  I find it very hard to explain the way I need this code is meant to work.  So, thank you for your time.

Comment: From what you show and what you say you want to define a class that handles the stuff. But given everything you've written in your question, it looks to me you have no idea where to begin with, and you have no idea of it means to do C++ OOP. So before blindly copy/pasting my code, open a book and **UNDERSTAND** what you do.